# Infinite Series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\zeta(2)-\sum_{n=1}^k\frac1{n^2}\right)^2$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, closed-form, riemann-zeta, zeta-functions

Evaluate:
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\zeta(2)-\sum_{n=1}^k\frac1{n^2}\right)^2$$

Recognizing that $\zeta(2)-\sum_{n=1}^k\frac1{n^2}$ can be written as $\psi_1(1+k)$ where $\psi_1(z)$ is the [trigamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigammaFunction.html),
What remains to be done is to evaluate:
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\psi_1^2(k+1)$$
Mathematica could not evaluate it in a closed form but the source assures that it exists.

If you liked this problem check out [Hard Definite integral involving the Zeta function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/909977/hard-definite-integral-involving-the-zeta-function?rq=1).

Comment: @DavidH Please don't mark this question as a duplicate as I would like to see other ingenious solutions to the problem

Comment: Your sum evaluates to $3\zeta(3)-\zeta(2)^2$.

Comment: @DavidH, it seems to me that the proposed duplicate talks about the derivative of the trigamma function $\psi'$, not about $\psi$ itself.

Comment: @IanMateus I think you're confused. $\psi$ represents the digamma function, not the trigamma function. The duplicate I proposed talks about the derivative the digamma function $\psi^\prime$, which *is* the trigamma function.

Comment: @DavidH I see, thanks! It is indeed a duplicate, then.

Comment: I cannot post an answer but I found that the result is $3\zeta(3)-\frac52\zeta(4)$ using standard summation techniques after writing the squared term as a series and expanding into two series.

Comment: @DivyanshGarg: While your question *is* a duplicate, seeing it lead me to the other question, to which I have added an answer. I hope that satisfies some of your desire to see other answers. (+1)

Answer (score 2):

Using Maple I am obtaining

$$\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \left( \Psi \left( 1,k+1 \right)  \right) ^{2}=
 0.9003626252$$